# Bootstrap4 - center span and inside link vertically

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 7 button links inside table, I added icons by using span and make them bigger I used "class=bigger", but now I am struggling with centering span and the rest of the text vertically (and horizontally) inside button.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container d-flex d-inline-flex align-self-center">
        <table id="main_menu" class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><a href='nasbrowser/index.php' class="btn btn-light btn-lg btn-block"><span class="bigger">&#x1F9EC</span> GATK analysis </a></td></tr>

                <tr><td><a href='nasbrowser/index.php' class="btn btn-light btn-lg btn-block">
                            <span class="bigger">&#x1F4BD</span> NAS browser</a></td>
                    <td><a href='nasbrowser/index.php' class="btn btn-light btn-lg btn-block"><span class="bigger">&#x1F4CA</span> Variant browser </a></td></tr>


                <tr><td><a href='nasbrowser/index.php' class="btn btn-light btn-lg btn-block" ><span class="bigger">&#x1F4D1</span> Anotator</a></td>
                    <td><a href='nasbrowser/index.php' class="btn btn-light btn-lg btn-block"><span class="bigger">&#x2702</span> Gene filterer</a></td></tr>

                <tr><td><a href='nasbrowser/index.php' class="btn btn-light btn-lg btn-block"><span class="bigger">&#x1F3AF</span> Coverage</a></td>
                    <td><a href='nasbrowser/index.php' class="btn btn-light btn-lg btn-block"><span class="bigger">&#x1F6CC</span> Bed uploader</a></td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

</div>
```

This is the result:
[image]

The underlined text is not vertically centered with the icon (I made green dot where I want the text).

Comment: Could you please explain a bit what you want it to look like? I tested your code and everything is centered, the picture + text is just shorter on some buttons than others. maybe you mean this? cause then you need to align the Pictures and Text at the start or end of the element or give the span a max-width etc. But everything is perfectly centered.

Comment: What do you mean? I tried your code and your span is already aligned both vertically and horizontally centered

Comment: sorry guys, I added the screenshot for clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flexible Box Layout Module, makes it easier to design flexible responsive layout structure without using float or positioning.

A Flexible Layout must have a parent element with the display property set to flex.

Direct child elements(s) of the flexible container automatically becomes flexible items.

```
.btn-block {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* to center elements vertically */
    justify-content: center; /* to center elements horizontally */
}

.bigger {
    font-size: 25px; /* just for chhecking purpose */
    margin-right: 10px; /* for spacing between icon and text */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works fine, the span and icon are centered horizontally and vertically.

Is it possible that you have a `margin-top` or `padding-top` somewhere on your links?